# Is There any way to find if a FormControl is readonly in angular

Tags: angular

I have a form control in my angular application.

```
const name = new FormControl('vikram');
```

and my template

```
<input type="text" formControlName="name" name="name" id="name" [attr.readonly]="true"/>
```

Is there any way in my component to find out if this control is read only?

Comment: read only: you want to read data not to edit right?

Comment: I have number of `FormControl` and i want to read value from `not readonly FormControl`

Comment: Try to look if `name` has an attribute `disabled`. I think that would be what you need.

Comment: Look currently you want to made the input as  read-only in some cases, you can check the same cases in your TS file and find out which is the formcontrols are readonly

Answer (score 1):

try this :

**html**

```
<input type="text" #nameCtrl formControlName="name" name="name" id="name" [attr.readonly]="true"/>
```

**ts**

```
...
      @ViewChild('nameCtrl', {static : true}) nameCtrl : ElementRef ;

      ngAfterViewInit(){
        console.log(this.nameCtrl.nativeElement.getAttribute('readOnly')) ;
      }
...
```

**Update**

A workaround to achieve this is to add a variable in your ts which contains readOnly attribute for each control :

**ts**

```
readOnlyFlags = {} ;
```

**html**

```
<input type="text" [formControl]="name" name="name" id="name" [attr.readonly]="readOnlyFlags['name'] = true" />

<input type="text" [formControl]="dob" name="dob" id="dob" [attr.readonly]="readOnlyFlags['dob'] = false" />
...
```

As result your readOnlyFlags will look like this :

```
{
  name : true,
  dob : false
}
```

finally you check the readOnly attribute for each form control like this :

```
readOnlyFlags['control_name']
```

Comment: I have number of form control i cannot do it for all

Answer (score 0):

you can get all the "formControls" in your component using ViewChildren

```
@ViewChildren(NgControl,{read:ElementRef}) controls:QueryList<ElementRef>
```

And search one in particular by attribute 'name', e.g.

```
  const control=this.controls.find(x=>x.nativeElement.getAttribute('name')=='name')
  return control?control.nativeElement.getAttribute('value'):null
```

Anyway, for me is a strange question. normally you use `[attr.readonly]="variable"`, so you only need ask about variable. you can get the value of any control in a form as `this.myform.get('nameOfFomControl').value` and if is diabled a control and you need the value use `this.myform.getRawValue()`